# modificar valor

Tags: php, pdo

saludos comunidad, quisiera tratar de actualizar el monto que tengo disponible con el nuevo monto a ingresar, ejemplo si me queda 5$ y quisiera ingresar 10$, seria 15$ que tendría ahora con el nuevo monto disponible anexo mi consulta y formulario, ya que no consigo lo requerido.

**update**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['edita'])){

$monto_nuevo=$_GET['monto_nuevo'];

$sql=$DB_con->prepare("UPDATE trasvalores SET  monto_trasvalores_apertura=:monto_trasvalores_apertura, 
monto_nuevo=(monto_trasvalores_actual + $monto_nuevo) WHERE 
id_trasvalores=:id_trasvalores");
$sql->bindParam(':monto_trasvalores_apertura',$_GET['monto_nuevo']);
$sql->bindParam(':monto_trasvalores_actual',$_GET['monto_nuevo']);
$sql->bindParam(':id_trasvalores',$_GET['id_trasvalores']);
$sql->execute();
if($sql)
{

     $successMSG = "¡ Bien Hecho: El monto del trasvalor a sido actualizado !";

 }

 else

  {

     $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: El Registro no se pudo actualizar !";

      }
   } 

?>
```

**formulario**

```
<?php
$id_trasvalores= $_GET['id_trasvalores'];
$consulta = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM trasvalores WHERE 
id_trasvalores=:id_trasvalores");
$consulta->execute(array(':id_trasvalores'=>$id_trasvalores));
$editar_linea = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);{
extract($editar_linea);
?>
<form class="col s12 m12 l12" action="actualizartrasvalores" 
name="frmContacto" method="GET">


<br>

<div class="input-field col s6 m4">
<input id="icon_prefix" class="black-text" type="text" 
name="monto_trasvalores_apertura" 
value="<?php echo $monto_trasvalores_apertura; ?>" autocomplete="off" 
title="Se necesito el monto!" 
pattern="[0-9]{5,15}" required/>
<label for="bancos" class="black-text ">Monto Apertura:</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s6 m4">
<input id="icon_prefix" class="black-text" type="text" 
name="monto_trasvalores_actual" 
value="<?php echo $monto_trasvalores_actual; ?>" autocomplete="off" 
title="Se necesito el monto!" 
pattern="[0-9]{5,15}" required/>
<label for="bancos" class="black-text ">Monto Actual:</label>
</div>




<div class="input-field col s6 m4">
<input id="icon_prefix" class="black-text" type="text" name="monto_nuevo" 
autocomplete="off" title="Se necesito el nuevo monto!" 
pattern="[0-9]{5,15}" required/>
<label for="nuevo monto" class="black-text ">Nuevo Monto:</label>
</div>




<div class="center-align">

<button class="btn waves-effect blue-grey darken-4 btn-medium" type="submit" 
name="edita">
Actualizar Registro
</button>

<a href='trasvalores' button class='btn waves-effect blue-grey darken-4 btn-
medium' type='submit'>Volver</button></a>

</div>

<input type='hidden' name='id_trasvalores' value='<?php echo 
$id_trasvalores; ?>'>
</form>
<?php

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pueden haber varias razones por la que no este actualizando el valor con la operacion de la suma. Aqui algunas:

Intenta utilizando el parametro binding `:monto_trasvalores_apertura` en tu sql y no la variable directa:

```
$sql=$DB_con->prepare("UPDATE trasvalores SET  monto_trasvalores_apertura=:monto_trasvalores_apertura, 
monto_nuevo=(monto_trasvalores_actual + :monto_trasvalores_apertura) WHERE 
id_trasvalores=:id_trasvalores");
```

Tambien deberias de confirmar que `monto_nuevo` tenga valor para que no este sumando con un valor `null`:

```
if(isset($_GET['edita']) && issset($_GET["monto_nuevo"])){
//..
```

Ten encuenta que la columna `monto_trasvalor_actual` puede ser null. Con la funcion [`IFNULL`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp) puedes saber si es null y si lo es, que lo sume con 0, de lo contrario con su valor:

```
 $sql=$DB_con->prepare("UPDATE trasvalores SET  monto_trasvalores_apertura=:monto_trasvalores_apertura, 
monto_nuevo=(IFNULL(monto_trasvalores_actual, 0) + :monto_trasvalores_apertura) WHERE 
id_trasvalores=:id_trasvalores");
$sql->bindParam(':monto_trasvalores_apertura',$_GET['monto_nuevo']);
$sql->bindParam(':monto_trasvalores_actual',$_GET['monto_nuevo']);
$sql->bindParam(':id_trasvalores',$_GET['id_trasvalores']);
$sql->execute();
```

Codigo completo:

```
if(isset($_GET['edita']) && isset($_GET["monto_nuevo"])){

$monto_nuevo=$_GET['monto_nuevo'];

     $sql=$DB_con->prepare("UPDATE trasvalores SET  monto_trasvalores_apertura=:monto_trasvalores_apertura, 
    monto_nuevo=(IFNULL(monto_trasvalores_actual, 0) + :monto_trasvalores_apertura) WHERE 
    id_trasvalores=:id_trasvalores");
    $sql->bindParam(':monto_trasvalores_apertura',$_GET['monto_nuevo']);
    $sql->bindParam(':monto_trasvalores_actual',$_GET['monto_nuevo']);
    $sql->bindParam(':id_trasvalores',$_GET['id_trasvalores']);
    $sql->execute();

 if($sql){
     $successMSG = "¡ Bien Hecho: El monto del trasvalor a sido actualizado !";
 }
  else{
     $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: El Registro no se pudo actualizar !";
  }
}
```

Comment: gracias amigo por tu respuesta lo he implementado pero me da el siguiente error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1582 Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\SATv0.1\admin\actualizartrasvalores.php:35 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SATv0.1\admin\actualizartrasvalores.php(35): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SATv0.1\admin\actualizartrasvalores.php on line 35

Comment: Perdón. Confundí ISNULL cuándo en realidad era IFNULL. Actualice mi respuesta dale una mirada

Comment: ahora me dice: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'monto_nuevo' in 'field list'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\SATv0.1\admin\actualizartrasvalores.php:33 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SATv0.1\admin\actualizartrasvalores.php(33): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SATv0.1\admin\actualizartrasvalores.php on line 33

Comment: En el SET del sql tienes una columna que se llama monto_nuevo y al parecer no existe en tu tabla. Seguro que esa es la columna que necesitas?

Comment: eso es lo que te iba a decir mi tabla es la siguiente: id_trasvalores,  monto_trasvalores_apertura, monto_trasvalores_actual, fecha, id_usuarios, pero en el formulario puse un input name="monto_nuevo" que seria para ingresar el nuveio monto

Comment: Tienes que reemplazar la columna monto_nuevo por una que si exista en la tabla.

Comment: que lo utilizaria para ingresar el nuevo valor, pero no se si esta mal hacerlo asi, te anexo una i agen para que me entienedas mejor https://prntscr.com/g8kd5z

Comment: El error es del sql no de tu interfaz. O creas una columna llamada monto_nuevo o utilizas una columna de la tabla. Ya eso es decisión tuya

Comment: podemos trasladar el debate al chat por favor